# How to call controller's action on click of link in extjs4

Tags: controller, extjs4, hyperlink

i am working in extjs4. I have gridview with links as=

```
{
            margin : '10 0 5 100',
            xtype : 'grid',
            id : 'g2',

            store : 'qb.qbquestionoptionStore',
            columns : [ {
                text : 'Options',
                dataIndex : 'option',
                flex : 1
            }, {
                text : 'Answer',
                dataIndex : 'isAnswer',
                flex : 2.5
            },
            {header : 'edit',
                renderer : function(val) {
                    //return '<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>';
                    return '<a href="#" onclick=" ">Edit</a>';
                }}}
```

So on click of above link i want to call controller's action. So how to implement this?
I have my app.js as-

```
Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'Balaee',
appFolder: 'app',

        controllers: [ 'Balaee.controller.qb.qbquestionController'
                             ],
launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', 
         {
            //id:'mainId',
            layout: 'auto',
            items: {xtype:'editView'}
        });
    }
});
```

I tried as-" 'Edit';" But its giving me error as "Balaee.app is undefined". So what i need to do

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control events of DOM element, it is good practice to bind DOM events in the View and then View should generate View's high level event to bind Controller to.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Virt/8xtAN/

Comments:

**View functions needed to bind DOM events to  element and generate event for Controller:**

```
    initComponent: function () {
        this.addEvents('editcompany');
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    afterRender: function () {
        this.mon(this.el, 'click', this.onEditClick, this, {
            delegate: 'a'
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    onEditClick: function (e, t) {
        e.stopEvent();
        var id = Ext.fly(t).getAttribute('dataValue');
        this.fireEvent('editcompany', id, this, e);
    }
```

**Controller functions to bind to View's event:**

```
    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'testgrid': {
                editcompany: function (companyId) {
                    alert('Edit Company ' + companyId);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @user1722857 was this answer useful?